# Automatically insert signature on class files

Tags: eclipse

I am about to complete a project and I'd like to edit each class file with something like that:

```
/**
 Class created by me, all rights reserved 
 and other stupid canonical stuff you can 
 often read **/
 public class AClassOfMine{
          ...
 }
```

is there some automated way to do so in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google returned me [JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/). It should suffice your needs:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/images/edit_header.gif))</sub>